# Move column of list view in backend to right

Tags: typo3

I am writing a typo3 plugin with a custom list view:
Here's the TCA:

```php
<?php

$extensionKey = 'sitepackage';

return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damageLog.lable',
        'label' => 'tenement_id',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'dividers2tabs' => true,
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
        ],
        'searchFields' => 'feuser_id,',
        'iconfile' => 'EXT:'.$extensionKey.'/Resources/Public/Icons/module.svg',
    ],
    'types' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' => 'hidden, reportarea, feuser_id, tenement_id, image1, image2, image3, image4, comment'],
    ],
    'palettes' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' => 'tenement_id, feuser_id'],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'hidden' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:hide.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
            ],
        ],

        'reportarea' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.servicetype.reportarea',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype_damage',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' ORDER BY name ',
                
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
            ]
        ],

        'tenement_id' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'Name (Adresse)',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_tenement',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' ORDER BY name ',
                
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
            ]
        ],
        
        'tstamp' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'Änderungsdatum',
            'config' => [
                'default' => 0,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'type' => 'input',
            ]
        ],

        'crdate' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:Creation date_all',
            'config' => [
                'default' => 0,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'type' => 'input',
            ]
        ],

        'image1' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
            ],
        ],

        'image2' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
            ],
        ],

        'image3' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
            ],
        ],

        'image4' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
            ],
        ],

        'image_1' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'image',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',
                    ],
                    'foreign_match_fields' => [
                        'fieldname' => 'image_1',
                        'tablenames' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_action',
                        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                    ],
                    'overrideChildTca' => [
                        'types' => [
                            'foreign_types' => [
                                '0' => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ],

        'image_2' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'image',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',
                    ],
                    'foreign_match_fields' => [
                        'fieldname' => 'image_2',
                        'tablenames' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_action',
                        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                    ],
                    'overrideChildTca' => [
                        'types' => [
                            'foreign_types' => [
                                '0' => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ],

        'image_3' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'image',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',
                    ],
                    'foreign_match_fields' => [
                        'fieldname' => 'image_3',
                        'tablenames' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_action',
                        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                    ],
                    'overrideChildTca' => [
                        'types' => [
                            'foreign_types' => [
                                '0' => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ],

        'image_4' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.image.lable',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'image',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference',
                    ],
                    'foreign_match_fields' => [
                        'fieldname' => 'image_4',
                        'tablenames' => 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_action',
                        'table_local' => 'sys_file',
                    ],
                    'overrideChildTca' => [
                        'types' => [
                            'foreign_types' => [
                                '0' => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                                    'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                                ],
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ],

        'comment' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.Comments.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
            ],
        ],
        
        'feuser_id' => [
            'exclude' => false,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_be.xlf:damage.User.lable',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                
                'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' ORDER BY username ',
                
                'size' => 1,
                'minitems' => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

And here the controller:

```php
<?php

namespace Homeinfo\Sitepackage\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList\DatabaseRecordList;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility as BackendUtilityCore;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\BackendTemplateView;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\BackendUserAuthentication;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\ViewInterface;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

class BackendController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    /**
     * Page uid
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $pageUid = 0;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $pageInformation = [];

    /**
     * BackendTemplateContainer
     *
     * @var BackendTemplateView
     */
    protected $view;

    /**
     * Backend Template Container
     *
     * @var BackendTemplateView
     */
    protected $defaultViewObjectName = BackendTemplateView::class;


    /**
     * Set up the doc header properly here
     *
     * @param ViewInterface $view
     */
    protected function initializeView(ViewInterface $view)
    {
        /** @var BackendTemplateView $view */
        parent::initializeView($view);
        $view->getModuleTemplate()->getDocHeaderComponent()->setMetaInformation([]);

        $pageRenderer = $this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer();
        //$pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/DateTimePicker');
        $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/ContextMenu');
        $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/AjaxDataHandler');
        $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/ColumnSelectorButton');
        $pageRenderer->addInlineLanguageLabelFile('EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf');
        $dateFormat = ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['USdateFormat'] ? ['MM-DD-YYYY', 'HH:mm MM-DD-YYYY'] : ['DD-MM-YYYY', 'HH:mm DD-MM-YYYY']);
        $pageRenderer->addInlineSetting('DateTimePicker', 'DateFormat', $dateFormat);
        $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/Element/ImmediateActionElement');
        // Setting up the context sensitive menu:
        $pageRenderer->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Backend/ContextMenu');

    
        $web_list_modTSconfig = BackendUtilityCore::getPagesTSconfig($this->pageUid)['mod.']['web_list.'] ?? [];

    }

    /**
     * Function will be called before every other action
     *
     */
    public function initializeAction()
    {
        $this->pageUid = (int)\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('id');
        $this->pageInformation = BackendUtilityCore::readPageAccess($this->pageUid, '');
        parent::initializeAction();
    }


    /**
     * Main action for administration
     */
    public function configurationAction()
    {
        // Cleaning
        $cleaninglist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $cleaninglist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype_cleaning', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $cleaninglist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype_cleaning' => []
        ];
        
        // Maintenances
        $maintenancelist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $maintenancelist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $maintenancelist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype' => []
        ];

        // Apartments
        $apartmentlist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $apartmentlist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_apartment', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $apartmentlist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_apartment' => []
        ];

        // Rooms
        $roomlist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $roomlist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_room', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $roomlist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_room' => []
        ];

        // Damage
        $damagelist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $damagelist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype_damage', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $damagelist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_servicetype_damage' => []
        ];
        
        // Contacts
        $contactlist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $contactlist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_contact', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $contactlist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_contact' => ['name','email', 'phone', 'street', 'house_number', 'zip_code', 'city', 'service']
        ];
        $this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer()->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Recordlist/Recordlist'); 
        $assignedValues = [
            'servicetypeCleaning' => $cleaninglist->generateList(),
            'servicetypeDamage' => $damagelist->generateList(),
            'apartments' => $apartmentlist->generateList(),
            'rooms' => $roomlist->generateList(),
            'serviceTypeMaintenance' => $maintenancelist->generateList(),
            'contacts' => $contactlist->generateList(),
        ];
        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);

       //DebugUtility::debug( $cleaninglist->getFieldsToSelect('tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_cleaning', $cleaninglist->setFields['tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_cleaning']), 'getFieldsToSelect');

        //$this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer()->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Recordlist/Recordlist'); 
       // $assignedValues = [
            //'page' => $this->pageUid,
            //'servicetypeCleaning' => $cleaninglist->generateList(),
            //'dataCount' => $cleaninglist->counter,
        //];

        //$this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);
        // \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($cleaninglist);
    }

    public function addressesAction()
    {
        $tenementlist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $tenementlist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_tenement', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $tenementlist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_tenement' => ['apartments']
        ];

        $assignedValues = [
            'tenements' => $tenementlist->generateList(),
        ];
        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);
    }

    public function appuserAction()
    {
        // User
        $userlist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $userlist->start(29, 'fe_users', 0, '', 0, 30);
        $userlist->setFields = [
            'fe_users' => ['name', 'email', 'telephone','address', 'crdate']
        ];

        // PIN
        $pinlist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $pinlist->start(6, 'tx_pinlogin_domain_model_pin', 0, '', 0, 30);
        $pinlist->setFields = [
            'tx_pinlogin_domain_model_pin' => ['name', 'pin', 'feuser_id']
        ];

        $this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer()->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Recordlist/Recordlist'); 
        $assignedValues = [
            'userlist' => $userlist->generateList(),
            'pinlist' => $pinlist->generateList(),
        ];

        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);
    }
    public function maintenanceAction()
    {
        $dblist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $dblist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_maintenance', 0, '', 0, 30);
        $dblist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_maintenance' => ['tenement_id,', 'apartment_id', 'room_id', 'servicetype_id', 'crdate','feuser_id']
        ];

        $this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer()->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Recordlist/Recordlist'); 
        $assignedValues = [
            'page' => $this->pageUid,
            'data' => $dblist->generateList(),
            'dataCount' => $dblist->counter,
        ];

        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);
    }
    
    public function cleaningAction()
    {

        $dblist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $dblist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_cleaning', 0, '', 0, 60);
        $dblist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_cleaning' => ['cleaningarea', 'duration', 'comment', 'crdate', 'feuser_id'] // => GeneralUtility::trimExplode(',', 'cleaningarea, duration, crdate, feuser_id', true)
        ];
       //DebugUtility::debug( $dblist->getFieldsToSelect('tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_cleaning', $dblist->setFields['tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_cleaning']), 'getFieldsToSelect');

        $this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer()->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Recordlist/Recordlist'); 
        $assignedValues = [
            'page' => $this->pageUid,
            'data' => $dblist->generateList(),
            'dataCount' => $dblist->counter,
        ];

        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);
        // \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($dblist);
    }

    public function damageReportAction()
    {
        $dblist = $this->getSettedDBList();
        $dblist->start(29, 'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_damage', 0, '', 0, 30);
        $dblist->setFields = [
            'tx_sitepackage_domain_model_reports_damage' => ['reportarea', 'tenement_id,', 'crdate', 'feuser_id', 'comment']
        ];
        //\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($dblist);
        $this->view->getModuleTemplate()->getPageRenderer()->loadRequireJsModule('TYPO3/CMS/Recordlist/Recordlist'); 
        $assignedValues = [
            'page' => $this->pageUid,
            'data' => $dblist->generateList(),
            'dataCount' => $dblist->counter,
        ];
        $this->view->assignMultiple($assignedValues);
    }

    private function getSettedDBList(): DatabaseRecordList
    {
        $dblist = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DatabaseRecordList::class);
        $dblist->clickTitleMode = 'edit';
        $dblist->showClipboardActions = true;
        //$dblist->noControlPanels = true;
        $dblist->displayColumnSelector = false;
        $dblist->displayRecordDownload = false;
        $dblist->pageRow = $this->pageInformation;
        @$dblist->counter++;
        $dblist->setIsEditable(true);
        return $dblist;
    }
    [...]
}
```

The damage report view looks like this:
[image]

I want to move the marked column with the control elements to the far right of the table.
How would I do that?

Comment: "Damage report view" sounds to me a bit like an own BE module instead of TYPO3s the normal list view. In a report, there's normally no need for up/down-sorting, or hiding records,... An own BE-modul with a table of records, maybe an edit/delete-button should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As are are using a "component" of TYPO3 (database record list) and there is no configuration for your request, there is currently no option to achieve that of the box.

You *could* use xclassing to completely change the rendering of such lists but  I don't know how many issues you face if you go down this roead